# Kendo UI dropdownlist search filter from client side not working in Version v2012.3.1315

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have kendo UI version v2012.3.1315. I tried with this code but didn't working

```
$("#CategoryId").kendoDropDownList({
            optionLabel: "Select category...",
            dataTextField: "Title",
            dataValueField: "ParentId",
            filter: "contains",
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "@Url.Action("CategoryJson")",
                        type: "POST",
                        cache: false
                    }
                }
            },
            @if (Model.CategoryId > 0)
            {
                @: dataBound: function (e) { console.log('catg loaded'); this.value('@Model.CategoryId'); }
                                                                            }
        });
```

search filter not applied to this dropdown

Comment: I think you will need to use the combobox rather than the dropdown list. I suspect this version may not have had filtering as a feature. I think this was introduced in a late 2013/2014 build of the kendo suite.

Comment: Yes it's working.. :-) Thanks. you saved my day.